# SQL - Update Junction Table Based on Values in User Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a new migration that creates a many-to-many relationship between a user and organization through a junction table called `organization_member`. Since I am trying to migrate the current values of the `organization_id` and `user_id` on the `user` table to the junction table to represent this relationship, I thought I would try a join and update, but I can't seem to figure out how to query both tables and then take the existing columns on `user` and update where the relationship doesn't currently exist. Here was my original thought:

```
UPDATE `om`
SET `om`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`, `om`.`organization_id` = `u`.`organization_id`
FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `organization_member` AS `om`
ON `u`.`user_id` = `om`.`user_id`
WHERE `u`.`organization_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

but I get an error at

```
'FROM `user` AS `u`
LEFT JOIN `organization_member` AS `om`
ON `u`.`user_id` = `o' at line 3
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the `JOIN` is part of the `UPDATE`.  There is no separate `FROM`:

```
UPDATE `user` `u` JOIN
       `organization_member` `om`
       ON `u`.`user_id` = `om`.`user_id`
    SET `om`.`user_id` = `u`.`user_id`,
        `om`.`organization_id` = `u`.`organization_id`
    WHERE `u`.`organization_id` IS NOT NULL;
```

A `LEFT JOIN` is also inappropriate.  You want to update `om`, so you need a matching row for the update